# Is bulk insert possible with any of ItemWriter in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

Currently am using JDBCBatchItemWriter to insert data into SQL server. Though the name of item writer says batch , I do see its inserting one record at a time rather doing batch/bulk insert. What confirguation I need to do for bulk insert?

Is there any other implementation class available to support it? Or please suggest what could be appropriate solution to achieve it.

Comment: please share your job config, especially the writer configuration

Comment: All updates in JdbcBatchItemWriter are bulk updates (have a look at the code https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.java)). Are you sure, that your writer receives a list of items and not just a list with only one item? Make a breakpoint in JdbcBatchItemWriter and debug into it.

Comment: writer config below
 
<bean id="a_writer" class="org.....JdbcBatchItemWriter"> <property name ="ds" ref="ds"><property name="sql"> <value><![CDATA[insert into aTbl (ac1, ac2, ac3) values (:acFst, :acSec, :acrd)]]></value></property><property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider"> <bean class="org......BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" /> </property></bean>.  If commit intvl is 100K then will the insert behave like this sql - "insert into trgtTbl (a1,a2,a3) select a1,a2,a3 from srcTbl" or insert each as a transaction? current behavior with db monitor shows each record as a transac.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of commit-interval specified for chunk element in your xml? It is the Number of items that will be processed before the transaction is committed.

Refer to the link: [configure a step in spring batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html)

Comment: I do see the JDBCBatchItemWriter is using Preparedstatement.executeBatch().  But looking into the DB monitoring tool it is showing each insert is considered as a transaction. Whereas if I do a insert Select , entire data insert is considered as one transaction. So my question is, if commit Interval is 100K, can it all be inserted as one transaction. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: one can not have just one transaction for the enitre batch as the database won't be able to cope with that. Just for the information,We define commit-interval at chunk level.So,each chunk is running its own transaction. There is a Completion Policy associated with the chunk. When it is satisfied, Spring batch stops reading and starts processing.When 'commit-interval' is defined, a 'SimpleComplettionPolicy' is used. One can define his own CompletionPolicy in the attribute chunk-completion-policy. Can you share your writer configuration? Because JdbcBatchItemWriter is for bulk updates